# Sqlmap parameter “might not be injectable”

Tags: sqlmap

I'm starting with sqlmap and I have the following problem: When I try to use sqlmap (trying to bypass waf) using this snippet:

```
sqlmap.py -u "http://prefing.umsa.edu.bo/index.php?option=com_newsfeeds&view=newsfeed&id=1&feedid=1&Itemid=18" --dbs --dbms=mysql --time-sec=10 --hex --level=5 --risk=3 --tamper=apostrophemask,apostrophenullencode,appendnullbyte,base64encode,between,bluecoat,chardoubleencode,charencode,charunicodeencode,concat2concatws,equaltolike,greatest,halfversionedmorekeywords,ifnull2ifisnull,modsecurityversioned,modsecurityzeroversioned,multiplespaces,nonrecursivereplacement,percentage,randomcase,randomcomments,securesphere,space2comment,space2dash,space2hash,space2morehash,space2mssqlblank,space2mssqlhash,space2mysqlblank,space2mysqldash,space2plus,space2randomblank,sp_password,unionalltounion,unmagicquotes,versionedkeywords,versionedmorekeywords
```

or this one:

```
sqlmap.py -u "http://prefing.umsa.edu.bo/index.php?view=article&catid=35:pagina-principal&id=44:inicio-central&format=pdf" --dbs --dbms=mysql --time-sec=10 --hex --string --regexp --level=5 --risk=3 --tamper=apostrophemask,apostrophenullencode,appendnullbyte,base64encode,between,bluecoat,chardoubleencode,charencode,charunicodeencode,concat2concatws,equaltolike,greatest,halfversionedmorekeywords,ifnull2ifisnull,modsecurityversioned,modsecurityzeroversioned,multiplespaces,nonrecursivereplacement,percentage,randomcase,randomcomments,securesphere,space2comment,space2dash,space2hash,space2morehash,space2mssqlblank,space2mssqlhash,space2mysqlblank,space2mysqldash,space2plus,space2randomblank,sp_password,unionalltounion,unmagicquotes,versionedkeywords,versionedmorekeywords
```

I saw that in the console appears:

```
[WARNING] heuristic (basic) test shows that GET parameter 'option' might not be injectable 
[WARNING] heuristic (basic) test shows that GET parameter 'view' might not be injectable
```

Also tried to find a URL inside my site similar to: `http://www.cafe53rd.com/menu.php?item_id=3` because I checked that this kind of url its easiest to access but I cant find it for the site I'm auditing.

What would be the right code to make it in the following [Site ("http://prefing...")](http://www.wilawara.com/list.html)

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking.  You need help finding URLs of a certain format?

Comment: If you are just starting with SQL Map, don't start with trying to bypass a WAF, start simple.  Disable the WAF for your audit.

Comment: first up, are you authorised to test the security of this system? If not, you shouldn't be running SQLmap against it.  If you are, then I would recommend testing without the WAF in place.

Comment: Ok I'll tell the teacher to disable the WAF.

Yes, my problem is finding vulnerable URLs recently found one that contains the terms:

/pre/login/login2.do?id_rol=pst0

I found it using  Vega software but now on the sqlmap console I get: "id_rol = pst0" is not injectable.

What can I do?

PS: This is part of a teams test that why I can´t have so much help by my teacher. Thanks